# Trigger auto deployment on bitbucket

Tags: git, capistrano

Currently, I deploy my code on my desktop.

However, my team member they are UI designer, they don't know how to deploy but only know how to use basic git push and pull.

I want to trigger the deployment when they push a new commit to the bitbucket.

I guess I need to put my deployment folder on the server, once the bitbucket commit triggered it will trigger the capistrano auto deploement.

Any direction to implement it?

Comment: I have a little idea what you are talking about, but I guess the [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) will be a good start.

Comment: `git hooks --help` may help. But I think you need a CI tool like Jenkins. Jenkins provides a lot of useful plugins, some of which are called Build Triggers. They can monitor your repo in the local or in the server. A jenkins job combines some necessary plugins, and can be triggered by events like `git merge`, `git commit`, `patchset merged`, `patchset created`, `patchset abandoned`,  or by a time interval, or by a CLI command, or by manual. These plugins can do the job more easily and more flexible.

Comment: You'll probably want to write a script for a `post-receive` hook https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html